# If $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$ then $Var(f,[a,b])\leq Var(g,[a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g\in BV([a,b])$

If $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$ then $Var(f,[a,b])\leq Var(g,[a,b])$

**My attempt:**

Let $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$, then

$Var(f,P)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|f(t_{i-1})-f(t_{i})|$ and 
$Var(g,P)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|g(t_{i-1})-g(t_{i})|$

As $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then

$f(t_{i-1})\leq g(t_{i-1})$ moreover $f(t_{i})\leq g(t_{i})$

this implies that:

$|f(t_{i-1})-f(t_{i})|\leq |g(t_{i-1})-g(t_{i})|$

in consequence:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|f(t_{i-1})-f(t_{i})|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|g(t_{i-1})-g(t_{i})|$$

is correct this?

Comment: Where does $f(t_i) \leq g(t_i)$ come from? The argument is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. On $[0,1]$ let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac  1 2 x+2$. Then $f(x) \leq 1 < g(x)$ for all $x$ but $var (g)=\frac 1 2 < 1=var (f)$.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.